# Split string at separator and create new dataframe

Tags: r

This seems like a basic question so please feel free to point me to another answer but I can't find an answer through my searching.

I have a set of 180,000 rows that looks like this:

`df <- c("12hfgog|hcsg9ws|xaw_07cas", "fhjf79", "8xxghk")`

I want to split the string at the delimiter "|" and create a new dataframe with the results that looks like this:

`df2 <- c("12hfgog","hcsg9ws", "xaw_07cas", "fhjf79", "8xxghk")`

I know it involves some combination of strsplit, unlist and unnest but I can't quite get it right. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You can use `library(tidyr); df %>% separate_rows(colname)`

Comment: `df2 <-unlist(strsplit(df, "\\|") )`

Comment: Thank you both! Excellent solutions!

Comment: Just to clarify -- are you looking for a character vector (df and df2 in your example), or a data.frame (i.e. rows and columns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is using sapply and strsplit. Later is only convert the resultant list to vector with unlist.

```
df1 <- c("12hfgog|hcsg9ws|xaw_07cas", "fhjf79", "8xxghk")
df2 <- unlist(sapply(df1, strsplit, split = "\\|", USE.NAMES = FALSE))
```

Regards.

Comment: `strsplit` is vectorized so you can skip `sapply` and as per @GordonShumway's comment (i.e.  `unlist(strsplit(df, "\\|"))`).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   separate_rows(colname)
```